# Blocks vs delegates or blocks vs methods

Tags: methods, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I have just studied blocks it is good ,easy to use,helps in inline coding and keeps thing at one place .But I am not able to understand the following two points clearly.

1)How blocks are different from methods and delegates?

2)Advantages of using blocks over methods and delegates.Where are blocks more useful than delegates and methods.

Kindly explain and help me in understanding the concepts better.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A seemingly curious question as you ask:

> 1)How blocks are different from methods and delegates?
>
> 2)Advantages of using blocks over methods and delegates.Where are blocks more useful than delegates and methods.

*After* you wrote:

> easy to use, helps in inline coding and keeps thing at one place

Regardless, though I maybe misunderstanding what you are after, here some further points to your own to consider in case they are helpful:

- Instance methods and delegates are both associated with an instance of an object; so there is a `self` with instance variables, properties and other methods all of which can be referenced and used. Both come with accompanying state.
- A block, like a function, is not associated with an instance of an object.
- A block however differs from a function in that it can capture values and variables (those annotated with `__block`) from the method/function they are defined within. So they carry some state.
- As to advantages of one over the others, it is really a question of picking the appropriate one for the scenario – none is "better" and the others. Decide what you need; adding behaviour to an object (method), passing an instance/method pair to provide some functionality (delegate), providing functionality based on values in the local scope (block), etc., etc.; and use the appropriate construct.

HTH